# What is the hetter to wear earmuffs?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Looking at all forms of traditionally Jewish hats, from hamburgs to streimuls to fedoras to beibers, and even the kangol cap, it is quite obvious our fathers and our fathers fathers did not want to cover their ears.

I have heard this has something to do with אוזן ששמע על הר סיני לא יהיה לך אלקים אחרים והלך זה ופרק מעליו עול מלכות  שמים וקבל עליו עול בשר ודם ירצע.
ירושלמי קדושין פ׳א ה׳ב.

In turn, our forefathers made certain that our ears not be mikabel any other type of burden. Ear coverings included.

So what is the hetter for seemingly otherwise religious Jewish people with all forms of traditional headwear putting on ear coverings? Whether they have rubber bands or they clip on, I wonder, is there a svara they are relying on?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

This is based on the verse:

[פָּקוֹחַ אָזְנַיִם וְלֹא יִשְׁמָע](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15973/jewish/Chapter-42.htm#v=20)

If you leave your ears uncovered, you won't hear G-d's message.

Earlier generations were on a much higher level and didn't have to be concerned about such things, but due to the low spiritual state of today, earmuffs should be worn at least a few months a year.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that our holy ancestors were avoiding is described precisely in the Yerushalmi - קבל עליו עול בשר ודם - they put a burden of flesh and blood on their ears.

In earlier generations, when hats and streimels, both made from animal products (hats are from rabbits, and streimels are from some kind of small furry woodland creature, I assume), were all that was available, they were careful to avoid any covering.

But today we have [180 earmuffs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003UNL2ZQ) made with synthetic Tec Fleece, so there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Well played indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks specifically about ear muffs, but your content says "ear coverings". I am inferring that you refer to anything that may cover your ears or any part of your ears including ear plugs, noise cancelling / reducing headphones, etc.

*Pirkei Avot* 5:7 describes the 7 differences between a *Golem* and a *Chacham*. Regarding the *chacham*, it says that one of his qualities is:

וְעַל מַה שֶּׁלֹּא שָׁמַע, אוֹמֵר לֹא שָׁמַעְתִּי

regarding what he did not hear, he says, "I did not hear"

So, in a sense, wearing anything that covers your ears, reduces your hearing, and, therefore, makes you smarter!

My advice ... go for it and cover your ears as much as you can!